# Adding an ID to the UI-form element

Tags: magento-2.1, html, uicomponent, magento2.1.0, ui-form

I have the element inside the UI-form:

```
return [
    'arguments' => [
        'data' => [
            'config' => [
                'componentType' => Modal::NAME,
                'dataScope' => '',
                'provider' => static::FORM_NAME . '.product_form_data_source',
                'id' => 'unique-id-html-attribute',
                'options' => [
                    'title' => __('Select Options'),
                    'buttons' => [
                        [
                            'text' => __('Save'),
                            'class' => 'action-primary',
                            'actions' => [
                                [
                                    'targetName' => 'index = create_something_form',
                                    'actionName' => 'save',
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'children' => [],
];
```

But I can not add the ID-attribute to the element. Line `'id' => 'unique-id-html-attribute'` does not work:

[image: result]

So question is: **How to add the ID-attribute to the UI-form element?**

Comment: How do you implement ui form without xml?

Comment: @mrtuvn It is not completely form without xml. You can see example at `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml`  where the form has been declared in xml, but almost all fields are added in modifiers (`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier`).

Comment: Yes i have already viewed it. But seem i do not find example about form modal with custom field not define in xml. Can i do modal ui form by add it inside renderer block or something

Comment: @mrtuvn I don't know whether it is possible without definition of the UI form in xml. Try to ask a question, perhaps somebody already tried to make it. And if I have free time - I will try to check it. PS: I can share only an example of addition of a modal window in the existing UI form.

Comment: It would be great if you share example modal

Comment: @mrtuvn Here is [example](http://blog.mageworx.com/2016/08/how-to-create-a-modal-window-in-a-custom-field-with-a-code-in-magento-2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration of your component defined using `config` array.
In this array there is `componentType` attribute, which defined in `etc/definition.xml` file (`Magento/Ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition.xml` for `modal` component).

The `definition.xml` configurations used for setting predefined configuration of components.

```
<modal class="Magento\Ui\Component\Container">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal-component</item>
            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">slide</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</modal>
```

This configuration will be merged with custom component configurations, defined in your module. If you dont define `component` parameter, then `Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal-component` will be used by default (defined in definition.xml).

Base `Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal-component` ui component use `ui/modal/modal-component` (`Magento/Ui/view/base/web/templates/modal/modal-component.html`) template.

```
return Collection.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'ui/modal/modal-component',
            title: '',
            subTitle: '',
```

In this template there are no any `id` bindings, thus `id` argument, defined in your configuration, does not appear on frontend.

```
<div css="modalClass" hasFocus="focused">
    <each if="state() || $data.modal" args="data: elems, as: 'element'" render=""/>
</div>
```

In your case you can use already existed `modalClass` option or write custom template for modal component:

*template.html*

```
<div data-bind="attr: {id: id}" css="modalClass" hasFocus="focused">
    <each if="state() || $data.modal" args="data: elems, as: 'element'" render=""/>
</div>
```

*Modifier.php*

```
'componentType' => Modal::NAME,
'template' => 'Custom_Module/modal/template',
'dataScope' => '',
```